# Navigation from block return

Tags: ios, multithreading, uinavigationcontroller

I have what I think is a [UX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) operation happening on a background thread. In a method that uses blocks, in the success I am calling:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
```

I am getting a crash, so I am thinking that checking the current thread and calling performSelectorOnMainThread might fix this, but I am not sure how to setup the @selector portion of the call.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector([self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE]) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

is not working. What is the proper syntax?

Comment: Just a minor point, but objective-c BOOL values are `YES,NO`, not `TRUE,FALSE`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To force the method to perform on the main thread you can use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE]; 
});
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but style-wise I prefer the higher-level: [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];}];

Comment: Eh, it's a toss-up for me…  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock is more versatile since it supports more functions like stop/start, dependencies etc.  But the lower-level language dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() (i.e. GCD) is a bit quicker.  Guess it depends on what you need...  But since popViewControllerAnimated: in this case is such a quick operation, maybe it doesn't require all the bells and whistles of the higher-level [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock...

Comment: For me it's not about the extra features, it's about which is more readable. And speed only matters if you test your code and find out it's slow. I find Objective-C much more readable than straight C, and the 'mainQueue' in the Objective-C interface jumps out a lot more than the dispatch_get_main_queue() in C. If you believe in Objective-C, you stay in Objective-C when you can.

Comment: `And speed only matters if you test your code and find out it's slow.`, but once you find out it's faster why not add that to your bag of tricks and use it as your primary solution the next time you encounter the scenario?

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, you can't directly do what you want because of the constraints of how `-performSelectorOnMainThread:` works. However, in whatever class `self` is, you could define a method like this:

```
- (void)doPop {
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

then

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doPop)];
```

To elaborate as to why you syntax isn't working:

The selector passes to `-performSelectorOnMainThread:` must be a selector that either takes no argument, or a single argument of some sort of `id`. While `-popViewControllerAnimated:` is a selector that takes a single argument, that argument is of type `BOOL` (which by the way uses `YES` and `NO` not `TRUE` and `FALSE`).

As well, the `@selector` will be just the name of the method, not the object you wish to invoke it upon (in this case, `self.navigationController`).

Think about it in terms of messaging objects. You want the `self.navigationController` object to perform the `-popViewControllerAnimated:` selector on the main thread, so you would construct the messaging that way:

```
[self.navigationController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

But the problem there is, again, the required argument. So since you cannot directly invoke `pop` in this manner, that's why my above suggestion. It allows you do invoke `perform` according to its semantics, then still call `pop` properly with its semantics.